# type comparison of each row in a large pandas data frame and change to similar type if not matching with others

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a large pandas data frame like below

```
    date           category
2018-03-01           abcd
2018-03-02           defc
2018-03-02 00:00:00  acd
2018-03-02 00:00:00  bac
2018-03-03           xyz
```

In the date column few of the entries consist of 00:00:00 or timestamp followed by date. And type of each row for date column without timestamp is **str** and with timestamp is **pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp**

**I need to check each row of date column and transform it to only date if it consists of any timestamp.**

I don't want to use for loop as it is a large data frame and it takes more computation time.

I have tried comparing for each row type for date column and than used **.strftime(format = '%Y-%m-%d')** to convert into date but how do i apply the same for the entire data set?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), errors='coerce')
```

Comment: will it remove the timestamp if present and keep only date?

Comment: @JahnabKumarDeka - you get `datetime`s, but if need only dates use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), errors='coerce').dt.date`